# SQL update - how to toggle?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a 'toggle' effekt in an SQL update statement. If the value of 'important' is `1` then query should update it to `0` and vice versa. If the value is `0` the query should update it to `1` within the database.

```sql
UPDATE items SET important = case when 0 then 1 else 0 end WHERE id = x
```

Comment: `case when important = 0 then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: Alternatively, `case important when 0 then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: `case when important then 0 else 1 end`, `important xor 1`, `if(important, 0, 1)`, `(important + 1) % 2`, `(important = 0)` and many other ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use arithmetic:

```
UPDATE items
    SET important = 1 - important
    WHERE id = x;
```

However, your code should also work.

Perhaps an even better way in MySQL is using `NOT`:

```
UPDATE items
    SET important = NOT important
    WHERE id = x;
```

This will not work in other databases, but it works in MySQL because it treats numbers as booleans in a boolean context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: Bravo. Though it's obvious I haven't even though about it.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to toggle, using [ELT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function

```
UPDATE items
SET important = ELT(important + 1, 1, 0)
WHERE id = x;
```

> ELT() returns the Nth element of the list of strings